# How to have struct data correctly displayed in a manifest based ETW provider?

Tags: xml, etw

I'm working on a COM program using C++. I would like to log all COM-Interface calls (including passed arguments) using Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) with a manifest.
As I have hundreds of different interface methods in my program, I would like to have a "generic" ETW event in my manifest that I can pass the interface name, the method name, and the arguments. So far, this is how my template for that event looks like:

```
<templates>
    <template tid="comInterfaceMethodCall" name="COM Interface Method Call">
        <data name="COM Object" inType="win:UnicodeString" />
        <data name="COM Interface" inType ="win:UnicodeString" />
        <data name="Interface Method" inType="win:UnicodeString" />
        <data name="Argument Count" inType="win:UInt16" />
        <struct name="Arguments" count="Argument Count" >
            <data name="Argument Name" inType="win:UnicodeString" />
            <data name="Argument Type" inType="win:UnicodeString" />
            <data name="Argument Value" inType="win:UnicodeString" />
        </struct>
        <UserData>
            <EventData xmlns="ProviderNamespace" name="COM Interface Method Call">
                <ComObject> %1 </ComObject>
                <ComInterface> %2 </ComInterface>
                <InterfaceMethod> %3 </InterfaceMethod>
                <Arguments> %5 </Arguments>
            </EventData>
        </UserData>
    </template>
</templates>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bwgg.png) is how the event looks like in the Event Viewer.
As you can see, everything is rendered correctly, except for the struct data which is shown as a hex binary string. I've checked the binary data and it is correct, so apparently I'm passing the data correctly to the EvenWrite function! I just want to have it rendered as strings, as stated in the manifest.

What I already tried: get rid of the struct and provide its members directly:

```
<data name="COM Object" inType="win:UnicodeString" />
<data name="COM Interface" inType ="win:UnicodeString" />
<data name="Interface Method" inType="win:UnicodeString" />
<data name="Argument Count" inType="win:UInt16" />
<data name="Argument Name" inType="win:UnicodeString" count="Argument Count" />
<data name="Argument Type" inType="win:UnicodeString" count="Argument Count" />
<data name="Argument Value" inType="win:UnicodeString" count="Argument Count" />
```

That works, but it's not what I want. For a method that has 10 arguments, it will show me 10 names first, then 10 types and finally 10 values. But I want to have 10 (name, type, value)-triples.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Before I can really answer this, I have to point out that ETW is not the same thing as EventLog. The two technologies are related and work together in many ways, but they're also somewhat independent.

At its core, ETW is just a system for transferring blobs of data from a producer to a consumer. As such, ETW can be said to support any kind of data.

There are several frameworks layered on top of core ETW that help you encode and decode your data. Manifests are one such system -- the manifest contains a description of the data structures that are expected for each of your ETW events. Based on the manifest, you can generate code for packing your data to create the blob. Based on the manifest, decoding tools can unpack the blob to generate a human-readable representation of your data.

EventLog is a system for recording, archiving, forwarding, and viewing important administrative events. EventLog has been around for a long time -- much longer than ETW, in fact. There are two different ways to send data to EventLog. The original EventLog supported the ReportEvent API, based on RPC. More recently, EventLog added support for consuming ETW events, i.e. you would tell EventLog what ETW events were important, and EventLog would listen for them and record them.

The problem you are seeing is that EventLog has a fairly simple view of what an event can contain. EventLog can only support a flat array of up to 99 fields in the event. All of the tools that work with EventLog expect events to work that way. When EventLog receives an ETW event, it has to find a way to fit the data from the ETW event into the simple EventLog view.

If you capture the trace directly using ETW tools, then decode the trace using an up-to-date ETW decoding tool, you'll see a much better view of your event. But if you use EventLog as the decoding tool, you'll see an EventLog view of your event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So you are saying that my manifest is correct, but EventLog is just not capable of rendering struct data? That's very disappointing as I had expected MS to provide a proper built-in consumer that is more compatible with what manifests provide... Assuming I can convince my customers to use a different consumer tool, is there a way to reference the struct's fields in the manifest? Right now I'm just using %5 to reference the entire struct. Something like %5.%1 would be helpful. The documentation of using manifests is just horrible....

Comment: EventLog is a large ecosystem. It provides an API, and that API provides a simple array system for accessing data from the event. It would require substantial breaking changes to this API to support more complex data structures. Instead of breaking the API, EventLog chose to flatten your structure into a single value, which provides the data without breaking the rest of the EventLog framework.